# How to pass data between UITabBar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitabbar

What is the best way to pass data between UITabBar. I know its easy to use prepare for segue but Im not using a story board for this project. thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use NSNotificationcenter & NSUserDefaults to save data .

Comment: Agree with @sourav. But I'm also adding the use of NSCoding. One other way would also be to customise your TabBarController so that it contains the common properties.

Comment: As per this type of requirement you can create a dictionary globally and access it any where in between the tabbar controller .

Comment: @sourav Thank you for the suggestion. I will use NSUserDefaults, the reason this is a bit difficult is because I'm retrieving the user coordinates. I was thinking of placing the func to save it to nsDefaults in in view will disappear but that will save it to NSUserdefaults  even when it is not necessary. How can I save only when a specific tab bar is selected.

Comment: I think you can add only a if condition for which tabbar you want to save NSUserdefaults .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the data you want to pass:

- If it's data to be used only in the destination view controller, you can simply define public properties and assign them on initialization and before presenting.
- If it's common data which can be used from both source and destination, then it's better to define a third party (Provider, Manager...) which can provide the common data for both.

Comment: @Moazz  Im passing the user current coordinates.

Comment: I recommend the second option in such case